# Reorder the content of BehaviourRelay<Array> without emitting

Tags: rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I have a situation at hand. I have a `designerDress:BehaviourRelay<[MyCustomObjects]>`
Already implemented in code which drives few UI components.

Now I have a requirement to reorder the array which is simple

```
let tempArray = designerDress.value
//tempArray.reorderAsperMywish()
designerDress.accept(tempArray)
```

But now it recreates the UI components.
My question is how can I **prevent or trap** a particular accept from emitting?

Comment: So to be clear, you *don't* want the UI to be a function of the state? If so, you can't have the UI updating when the state changes.

Comment: Why are you changing the `designerDress` if you don't want to change the UI?

Comment: I'm asking the above questions because what you are asking for is like asking to change the value of a String but having it return the old value when queried.

Comment: @DanielT. sorry for the delayed response. Actually its a old code in which it is assumed that only unique lements will be a added into array which will be accepted in relay but reordering was new requirement which was accepteing objects which where already accepted once before causing some duplication on VC. I refactored the code entirely as a quick fix would have been harmful. Thanks for your question I also agreed that its not good to go against very behaviour of Behaviour Relay